# Need to simplify ratio test: $\frac{(2(k+1))!}{(2k)!} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, factorial

So I am going to check if this series converges.
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(2k)!}{k^{k}} $$

I used the ratio test for this, and I end up with this limit:
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{(2(k+1))!\cdot{k^{k}}}{(2k)!\cdot{(k+1)}^{k+1}}$$

I have no clue on how I simplify: $$\frac{(2(k+1))!}{(2k)!} $$
I know for instance:
$$\frac{(k+1)!}{k!} = k+1 $$

But the constant 2 infront of the brackets and inside the !-sign makes me a bit confused. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 6):

$$\frac{(2(k+1))!}{(2k)!}=\frac{(2k+2)!}{(2k)!}=\frac{(2k+2)(2k+1)(2k)!}{(2k)!}$$

Comment: Argh...I should have seen this! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

$(2(k+1))! = (2k+2)! = (2k!)(2k+1)(2k+2)$, so your last fraction simplifies to $(2k+1)(2k+2)$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{(2(k+1))!}{(2k)!} = \frac{(2k+2)!}{(2k)!} = \frac{(2k+2)(2k+1)\color{red}{(2k)}\color{green}{(2k-1)}\dots}{\color{red}{(2k)}\color{green}{(2k-1)}\dots} = (2k+2)(2k+1)$$

Comment: Argh...I should have seen this! Thanks a lot.